# How to Get Checked items in CheckBoxTreeView in JavaFx

Tags: javafx

How to Get *Checked* items in CheckBox TreeView in JavaFx?
I don't know how to achieve this... You only get the *selected* items...

```
ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> items = treeHazardsXmi.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using `CheckBoxTreeItem`s, you can iterate through the tree and test each one's `selected` property:

```
ObservableSet<CheckBoxTreeItem<?>> checkedItems = FXCollections.observableHashSet();
findCheckedItems((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) tree.getRoot(), checkedItems);

 // ...

private void findCheckedItems(CheckBoxTreeItem<?> item, ObservableSet<CheckBoxTreeItem<?>> checkedItems) {
    if (item.isSelected()) {
        checkedItems.add(item);
    }
    for (TreeItem<?> child : item.getChildren()) {
        findCheckedItems((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) child, checkedItems);
    }
}
```

If you have a very large tree, for which that is computationally prohibitive, you can maintain a set of checked items, and by observing each item's `selectedProperty`, keep the set updated at all times. The downside here is that you have to be vigilant to always create the `CheckBoxTreeItem` so that it updates the set:

```
private ObservableSet<CheckBoxTreeItem<?>> checkedItems = FXCollections.observableHashSet();

private <T> CheckBoxTreeItem<T> createTreeItem(T value) {

    CheckBoxTreeItem<T> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(value);

    item.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasChecked, isNowChecked) -> {
        if (isNowChecked) {
            checkedItems.add(item);
        } else {
            checkedItems.remove(item);
        }
    });

    return item ;
}
```

Now, as long as your items are created via the `createTreeItem()` method, the `checkedItems` set will always contain the checked items.

Note that if your tree is dynamic (you add and remove nodes at runtime), you should go further and deregister the listener if the item is removed from the tree (left as an exercise for the reader...).